# Delphi TLV Encoding

Tags: delphi, tlv

I am trying to make a TLV Encoding format. I have managed to do the flowing:

```pascal
TagValueLen := Length(TagValue);
TagBuf := IntToHex(TagNum,2);    // String
TagValueLenBuf := IntToHex(TagValueLen,2);   // String
TagValueBufArr := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TagValue);  // Tbyte Array
```

I think all I need now is to concat all 3 values to create the TLV,
but how do I convert the hexadecimal strings (not exceeding 'ff') to one `TBytes` array?

Comment: Don't convert to hex strings, convert directly to byte array

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for reply I have tried that but I need the hexadecimal value for the integer 21=15  if I used TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes() it takes a strange  and  '21'<>15 hexadecimal  ,  can you give me an example.

Comment: @ammar why have you got the decimal number `'21'` in a string? Where does that come from?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if I wanted to use  TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes it has to be a string, can you offer another way to do it ?

Comment: @Ammar So long as `TagValueLen` and `TagNum` are in the range 0..255 you can assign them directly to bytes, or to elements of a byte array. e.g. `arr[0] := TagValueLen` and `arr[1] := TagNum`. Then you just need to copy the bytes from your call to `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes` onto the end of the array. I mean, I'm guessing a lot here since you didn't state clearly what TLV is. But I'm pretty confident that you don't need to convert anything to a hex string in order to make a byte array.

Comment: One of the common misunderstandings we see when working with byte arrays is that people can tend to fixate on hexadecimal. Hexadecimal is just a representation of a number. But `255 = $ff` because these are the same numbers. How you represent them doesn't change the value. It's important to understand that in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan actually I have tried this before and it worked in some cases, I got the same result now "Not working with arabic text", I think I have an issue elsewhere in the code thank you very much for your help I was stuck in the wrong place , also TLV is encoding  Tag-Length-Value format

Comment: OK, so in my comment above, I had `[0]` and `[1]` reversed, but I'm sure you can work out the details from here.